# Unable to play video in videoview from youtube url

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-videoview, android-video-player

I want to play following youtube url in android VideoView but it is not streaming video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-gEwftyPCg

Following is my code

```
   VideoView videoView = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealVideo);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(getContext());
        mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-gEwftyPCg"));
        videoView.start();
```

**I want to support non youtube video url as well**

Comment: VideoView can play only video files. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-gEwftyPCg` will give you HTML page. That's why it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not play youtube link directly in VideoView.

You need to integrate youtube player.

Check this out how to do that: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: will it support non youtube url

Comment: @apk no, it only support youtube video. so you need to filter out normal video url and youtube video url and play accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I found this way of implementation.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_fragment, container, false);

    String frameVideo = "<html><body><br><iframe width=\"320\" height=\"200\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XDYbEuY8nIc\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
  return rootView;
    }
```

inside the layout.xml:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"/>
```

This will work well.

Comment: How is this implemented? How is it added to the layout for example? Did you make a CustomVideoView class that extended VideoView and did you override onCreateView? 
Quite a creative solution! Thanks for any response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

accept permission